# By default today's date in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

I am using datepicker in my project. I want to select by default today's date, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".datepickclass").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

OR

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepickerid").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

OR

Set to today:

```
$('#datepickerid').datepicker('setDate', '+0');
```

For Bootstrap Datepicker

```
$('#dob').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$('#dob').datepicker('update');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DwT8M/8/)

Comment: it is not showing the current date on the text box by default,please help me out

Comment: this is how it is done for me <script>  
var plus14days = new Date();

  plus14days.setDate(plus14days.getDate());
  $("#c_date").datepicker("setValue", plus14days);
  $("#c_date").datepicker('update');
</script> anyway thanks for ypur help

Answer (score 0):

use **php** date instead of js date (js uses system date - it will not correct at all)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('SetDate', '<?php echo date('y-m-d');?>');
```